# SPFolder.MoveTo when running as user who does not have access to folder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

How do you copy a folder in a document library - that the current user does not have access to - to another document library?

The current user has access to the root of the document library and can see all files at this level. They cannot see the folder as it has unique permissions set on it.

The moving of the folder can be instigated by any user and is done via a custom edit control block control.

I have tried `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, but it does not work:

```
//Some previous code
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
            {
                foreach (SPFolder folder in item.Folder.SubFolders)
                {
                    if (folder.Name == "Confidential")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            folder.MoveTo(newLib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + item.Name + "/Confidential");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` code block has no effect in your case, as the item and web objects are created outside that scope. The folder objects you perform the `MoveTo` method on are received from the item, that is not "elevated". You should get site / web / list (etc.) objects you need to perform operations with elevated permissions to create within the elevated scope:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
    {
      using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
      {
        SPList elevatedLib = elevatedWeb.Lists["YourDocLib"]; // that is the elevated newLib
        SPListItem elevatedItem = elevatedLib.GetItemById(item.ID);
        foreach (SPFolder folder in elevatedItem.Folder.SubFolders)
        {
            if (folder.Name == "Confidential")
            {
                try
                {
                    elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    folder.MoveTo(elevatedLib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + elevatedItem.Name + "/Confidential");
                }
                finally
                {
                    elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Spot on pholpar. I had to make a small change, but works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code in the end for the benefit of others.

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite esite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
            {
                using (SPWeb eweb = esite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
                {
                    SPList eoldLib = eweb.Lists[oldLib.Title];
                    SPList enewLib = eweb.Lists[newLib.Title];
                    SPListItem eitem = eoldLib.GetItemById(item.ID);
                    foreach (SPFolder folder in eitem.Folder.SubFolders)
                    {
                        if (folder.Name == "Confidential")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                eweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                folder.MoveTo(enewLib.RootFolder.Url + "/" + eitem.Name + "/Confidential");
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                eweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```